# Optimizing Gulp tasks

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have the following tasks as part of my gulp file:

```
gulp.task('jshint', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});

gulp.task('jscs', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(jscs());
});

gulp.task('jslint', [ 'jshint', 'jscs' ]);
```

As I understand it, if I run `jslint` I'm not going to get the benefit of only reading from disc one. To do that, I would have to rewrite it to look like this:

```
gulp.task('jslint', function() {
    return gulp.src(jsSrc)
        .pipe(jshint())
        .pipe(jscs())
        .pipe(jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
});
```

This is fine, except that it doesn't allow me to run the `jshint` task independently of the `jscs` if I wanted to.

Hence I'm wondering what best practice is around this? I was thinking that I could break things out into different functions and orchestrate things together, but that doesn't seem like the right approach.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I have seen and used is:

```
var merge = require('merge-stream');

gulp.task('analyze', function() {
    var jshint = analyzejshint(config.js);
    var jscs = analyzejscs(config.css);

    return merge(jshint, jscs);
});

function analyzejshint(sources, overrideRcFile) {
    var jshintrcFile = overrideRcFile || './.jshintrc';
    console.log('Running JSHint');
    return gulp
        .src(config.js)
        .pipe(plug.jshint(jshintrcFile))
        .pipe(plug.jshint.reporter('jshint-stylish'));
}

function analyzejscs(sources, overrideRcFile) {
    var jscsrcFile = overrideRcFile || './.jscsrc';
    console.log('Running JSCS');
    return gulp
        .src(config.js)
        .pipe(jscs(jscsrcFile))
}
```

If you wanted to perform just one, you can just return the stream from one of the functions instead.